# Ruby on rails, how to return the amount of days objects were created for that time period

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So say I have a `channel`, and it `has many entries`. Daily that channel can have entries for many users. I want to be able to report how many entries there were during the week, but I only want to show how many days a entry was created. So I don’t want to show how many entries were created that week, just how many days an entry happened.

example:

`channel.entries.for_week(current)`  returns all of the entries that have been made this week.

I Just want to return the amount of days entries were made for that channel.  Anybody have a good solution for this?

Comment: What do you want exactly? If a channel have 2 entries, one made for 3 days, another of 4 days, the result you want is?   7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use something like this.

```
channel.entries.for_week(current).pluck(:created_at).map(&:to_date).uniq.count
```

Comment: Your instance doesnt return all of the entries

Comment: @Ilya what do you mean by all of the entries?

Comment: `ActiveRecord::Relation` object

Comment: That's his logic. `I Just want to return the amount of days entries were made for that channel`